# How to get value from json data by using JsAction?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

How to get Json value by using JsAction? How to acees firstname?  i would like to show any value from Json value.

Controller:

```
   [JsAction()]
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetStudent(int a)
        {

            Student st =   new Student() { firstName = "yusuf", lastName = "karatoprak", SumHere = 5 };
            return Json(st, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

View:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        JsActions.Home.MyTestMethod(1, 2).then(function (data) { alert(data); });
        JsActions.Home.MyTestMethod2(4, 5).then(function (data) { alert(data); });
        JsActions.Home.Yusuf(67, 9).then(function (data) { alert(data.toString()); });
        var ret = JsActions.Home.GetStudent(6);

        alert(ret.firstName);

        console.log(ret.firstName);

    })
```

But i can not access firstname. i see some code form codeplex:

[image]

Comment: based on codeplex example I think ret should be assigned like this var ret = JsActions.Home.GetStudent(6).responseText; now you should be able to do  alert(ret.firstName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //JsActions.Home.MyTestMethod(1, 2).then(function (data) { alert(data); });
        //JsActions.Home.MyTestMethod2(4, 5).then(function (data) { alert(data); });
        //JsActions.Home.Yusuf(67, 9).then(function (data) { alert(data.toString()); });
// old var ret = JsActions.Home.GetStudent(6)
// new one
        var ret = JsActions.Home.GetStudent(6).responseText;

        alert(ret.firstName);

        console.log(ret.firstName);

    })
```

Note: your controller just speaks about GetStudent method so I commented other method calls.

Comment: troubleshoot: 1. debug and see if GetStudent method is invoked or not. 2. if method is invoked, then check if you have added jQuery references (jQuery1.7 or >) to your webpage.

Comment: JSAction doesent not require  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet adn [httpGet], try removing those two